# Ruby Certificate Error

Tags: ruby, installation, crm

I am trying to install a migration tool called move to go for a CRM system called Lime but I get an error. I dont know why, the certificate says it's valid in the SSL.

This is the step by step guide that I am executing: 
https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go/blob/master/step-by-step.md

and this is the documentation: 
https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go

```
C:\Users\gujo>gem install move-to-go
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'move-to-go' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, especially http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html which is long but will help you ask questions. "[mcve]" is also important. You say you're following the steps in the linked pages, but we can't confirm that you are because you're not telling us enough. Also, please format your text so it's readable. That helps us understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, will do, sorry, very new here.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Ruby SSL certificate that has changed.
You can install a newer version of RubyGem to fix the issue.

Example, on Windows:

1. Download `https://rubygems.org/downloads/rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem` and save it to `C:\rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem`
2. Open a command prompt and run the commands :

   - `gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem`
   - `update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc`
   - `gem --version` and check it is 2.6.7
   - `gem uninstall rubygems-update -x` to remove the update package

Finally, retry your `gem install` command and the SSL error should be gone !

Source: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#installing-using-update-packages